# Text is widely spaced even though line-height is set to 1

Tags: html, css

Looking at the widely spaced text that's in the center of this site: http://www.sharonhadary.com/ .

I tried setting the `line-height` property to 1 in the web inspector (it was originally set to 1em), but this had little effect.  This is surprising to me, because it looks like that text has a line height of 2 or 3.

Comment: From a quick inspection, a few of your individual tags have a line-height of 1.2em. Changing this resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Yes Paulie_D, and finding a minimal example will help lead to the answer.  Currently making a fiddle.  SArnab thanks, gonna look.

Comment: Why would you still use the font tag? It is **not supported** in HTML5. Use a span and CSS instead.

Comment: Your line-height is relative to your font-size. Meaning that you have a 1.1em of 100px

Comment: Using the Font tag because this is a Weebly site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the giant `font-size` and it's fixed.

```
.banner-wrap .banner h2 {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    word-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    /* font-size: 100px; */ /*REMOVE THIS */
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}
```

[image]

Also `<font>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used

Comment: Oddly, the text is at 16px.  I'm not sure what is at the font size 100px, I'm now investigating that.  https://media.giphy.com/media/WM3HX2cZ3zTry/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `line-height: 22px` instead of 1em.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your problem correctly but

1) If you are concerned about spacing in text, remove `"word-spacing: .1em;"` from `.banner h2` CSS rule in the `main_style.css`.

2) If you are concerned about spacing between lines, reduce `line-height` in the `.banner h2` CSS rule in the `main_style.css`.